# SpringMVC Klick on Table Row?

Tags: spring, jsp

Hi i have spring application which shows some values from the database in a table from jsp.
Now i want to add functionality that when a user clicks on one row to know which row he has clicked to delete or edit row 
How is that to be accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compile jsp page you can assign an id to every row. Put this id inside hidden and send it back on delete or update action.

```
   <tr> 
    <td>   
        <form name="myform" action="..." method="...">
        <input type="hidden" name="Language" value="rowNumber">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
        <br><br>
        </div>
    <td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: hello but i can't assign to un an undefined number of rows some id s per hand because it should be dynamic there should be an automated id genereation

thank you

Comment: You said that jsp is populated from database. This means you should populate jsp with data that is selected from db. At this stage(building jsp) you can specify ids depends on database data. If you have another case, please describe it more detail.